# Python selenium can't click multiple div because of same class

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to achieve multiple div to get a click in the same class but it's ain't so helpful
[Sit Plan][1]
https://ibb.co/SfdT2LW

**This is the code**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="seat" title="[GHA-15]" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" onclick="chooseSeat(this)">0-4-5                                                                
                                <div class="spinner">
                                                                    <div class="double-bounce1"></div>
                                                                    <div class="double-bounce2"></div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </a>

<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="seat" title="[GHA-14]" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" onclick="chooseSeat(this)">0-2-5                                                                
                                <div class="spinner">
                                                                    <div class="double-bounce1"></div>
                                                                    <div class="double-bounce2"></div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </a>
```

**That's how I tried . but work for single div only **
'''

```
div = driver.find_element_by_class_name("spinner")
div.click()'''

This is what i tried from Web. but is'nt helping
''' 
div1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[@class="seat"]//preceding-sibling::td[@div="spinner"]')
# div1.click()
```

'''

Answer (score 1):

to differentiate between

`0-4-5` and `0-2-5` you can simply use the `title attribute`(`xpath`) from the shared HTML.

```
//a[@title='[GHA-15]']
```

should represent `0-4-5`

`//a[@title='[GHA-14]']` for `0-2-5`

Click it like:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@title='[GHA-15]']").click()
```

or

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@title='[GHA-14]']"))).click()
```

**Update:**

There are multiple ways to click on the spinner element.

1. Use `XPath-indexing:`

   ```
   driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//div[@class='spinner'])[1]").click()
   ```

   or

   ```
   WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//div[@class='spinner'])[1]"))).click()
   ```
2. Use `find_elements`

   ```
   elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='spinner']")))
   elements[0].click()
   ```

   or

   ```
   elements[1].click()
   ```

   etc.
3. click in a loop:

   ```
   elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='spinner']")))
   for element in elements:
       element.click()
       time.sleep(3)
   ```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thanks, But I don't want to specify with GHA-15 or GHA-14 , because some time there will be some other seats available.

Comment: okay which element you are looking for then, I see `<div class="spinner">
 <div class="double-bounce1"></div>
 <div class="double-bounce2"></div>
  </div>` in the HTML DOM, you want to retrieve both of them or Just first or second?

Comment: Also, Is it possible to share link to the page?

Comment: <div class="spinner"> I want to click both of them, one after one . but it's clicking same div with this code = div = driver.find_element_by_class_name("spinner")
div.click()

Comment: https://ibb.co/DrnB7VY it's possible but you need account there .

Comment: Checkout the updated code above under update section.

Comment: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <div class="spinner"> is not clickable at point (487,749) because another element <div id="ui-tooltip-1" class="ui-tooltip ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-widget-content"> obscures it    #Just clicking one spinner. I don't understand what's happening 

Comment: <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="seat" title="[NEO-19]" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" onclick="chooseSeat(this)">5-4-6                                                                <div class="spinner" style="">
                                                                    <div class="double-bounce1"></div>
                                                                    <div class="double-bounce2"></div>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </a> #this one avalble seat

Comment: <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="booked seat" title="[NEO-20]" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom">5-5-6</a> #####this is a booked seat

Comment: <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="seat selected" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" onclick="chooseSeat(this)" title="[NEO-11]">5-4-4                                                                <div class="spinner" style="">                                                                    <div class="double-bounce1"></div>                                                                    <div class="double-bounce2"></div> </div>
                                                            </a> #is a selected seat  and i want o select available seat .

Comment: Your comments have confused me. which code did you try and did not work? Also, do you have test account that I can use to replicate the same issue at my end ?

Comment: YOU CAN USE MY ACCOUNT , HOW CAN I CONTACT YOU?

Answer (score 1):

***Using following way you can select the required div when the multiple div have the same class name***

```
select=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="class name"][index of div]')
```

Here class name is the name of div class and the index is the index of div which you want to select it start from 1 to onward

Answer (score 0):

get all element with same class using:

```
elms = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "seat")
```

then iterate through the list to get what you are looking for

```
for elem in elems:
    if # your condition:
        # do your stuff
```